# On hover; menu will slide onto the screen

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a news box, and when you hover the little tab, hanging on the right side, then the news box is sliding onto the screen, i have a picture that it should look like, but the picture shouldn't used, but instead for information, how it actually should look like.

[Picture i want it to look like](http://www.arcane-swift.dk/Jquery-test/Test/Testing/Moretestplz/Testpic123.png)

I have tried to make it, but i dont think it should be made that way.

I think its made wrong

I dont know how to make it a link, so its amateur link

<kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://www.jsfiddle.net/Z8q5g/)**</kbd>

```
$(".menu").hover(function(){
    $(this).stop(true, false).animate({ width: "300px" });

}, function() {
    $(this).stop(true, false).animate({ width: "75px" });
});
```

Comment: What you had tried so far ? Please post your code.

Comment: What are you trying to do here because the hover function works just fine..

Comment: @Sulthan Allaudeen should i post my code, when i have linked fiddle?

Comment: You used text-align:center; in your css just remove that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your

```
text-align:center;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Z8q5g/2/

and it should be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If I get what you mean, you can do this with css only.
http://jsfiddle.net/Z8q5g/3/

```
<style>
  nav .item > a {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #888;
  }

  nav .item .bla {
    display: none;
    background: #000;
  }

  nav .item:hover .bla {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
</style>

<nav>
  <div class="item">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <div class="bla">
      <a href="#">Blabla</a><br />
      <a href="#">Blabla2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: it should be like i made it in my example. It should be like, news tap in the side, when you hover it, then it gets extended so you can see what is in there.